# binary tree insertion

Tags: c

In the following code i am getting compilation error:c2227:left of -> left must point to class/struct/union/generic type. any help how to fix this; I am trying to insert in a binary tree.

```
typedef struct bnode{
        int key;
        struct bnode* left;
        struct bnode* right;
        }BNODE;

void printKeysReverse(BNODE* current);
void inorder(BNODE* current);
void insert(BNODE **root,int key);
int main(void){
    BNODE* root=NULL;

    insert(&root,27);
    insert(&root,59);
    insert(&root,21);
    insert(&root,38);
    insert(&root,54);
    insert(&root,63);
    insert(&root,8);
    insert(&root,70);
    insert(&root,15);

}
void insert(BNODE **root, int val){
  BNODE *newnode;

  newnode=(BNODE*)malloc(sizeof(BNODE));        
  newnode->right=NULL;
  newnode->left=NULL;

  if ((*root)==NULL){
       *root=newnode;
       (*root)->key=val;              
       return;
       }
  if (val<(*root)->key) insert((&root)->left,val);
  else insert((&root)->right,val);     
}//end
```

Comment: You are leaking memory. If the function chooses to recurse, it has already allocated a node that will never be pointed at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(&root)->left
&root is NOT a BNODE*

Answer (score 0):

```
void insert(BNODE **root, int val){
BNODE *newnode;

newnode= malloc(sizeof *newnode);        
newnode->right=NULL;
newnode->left=NULL;
newnode->key=val;

while (*root){
   if (val < (*root)->key) root = &(*root)->left;
   else root = &(*root)->right;     
   }
*root=newnode;

return;


}
```